# angular subscribe data json value

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5 and my below function is posting the data to the server

```
doLogin(){
  var link = 'https://www.sportsmanager.us/Ionic/ASPPages/IonicRMLogin.asp?Login=T&O=2';
  var myData = JSON.stringify({txtEmailAddress: this.txtEmailAddress,txtPassword:this.txtPassword});
  this.http.post(link, myData)
       .subscribe(data => {
      alert(data['code'])
   }, error => {
     alert("Oooops!");
  });


}
```

and server return the json in following formart

```
{"code":"0","msg":"The email address entered is not assigned to any adult coaches. Please try a different email address or contact your administrator for assistance.", "page":"IonicRMHome.asp"}
```

when I try to get code value through data['code']. I get undefined error.

Comment: try data.code instead of data['code']

Answer (score 1):

Just do `console.log(data)` and you will get to see why it is giving error.

As my guess is that it is a json response, and it has `data.detail.code`.

Answer (score 1):

Data from server always comes as string. So, please parse it before using

Try

```
  this.http.post(link, myData)
       .subscribe(data => {
       data = JSON.parse(data);
      alert(data['code'])
   }, error => {
     alert("Oooops!");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your error message it seems like you have passed wrong email address to API but if your email address is correct then you can try to check with below code as there is no need to use `JSON.stringify` if your API accept `Content-type: application/json`:

```
doLogin() {
  const link = 'https://www.sportsmanager.us/Ionic/ASPPages/IonicRMLogin.asp?Login=T&O=2';

  const myData = {
    txtEmailAddress: this.txtEmailAddress,
    txtPassword: this.txtPassword
  };

  this.http.post(link, myData).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }, error => {
   alert("Oooops!");
  });
}
```

if your API do not accept `Content-type: application/json` then you have to add header in your POST API call as below :

```
this.http.post(link, myData, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type', 'Content type accepted by API'),
}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
}, error => {
  alert("Oooops!");
});
```

Comment: When I try this. I am getting HttpHeaders is not defined error.

Comment: import `HttpHeaders` from `@angular/common/http`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it done by doing it in following way :

```
let dataJSON = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
```

Comment: that is what my answer is

Comment: Could you please help me more time data is not submitting to the server ? Please let me know where is the issue ? I mean when I try var myData = JSON.stringify({txtEmailAddress: this.txtEmailAddress,txtPassword:this.txtPassword}); I am getting blank value at server side